# How to add the first of the month for gaps in dates BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am working on generating previous months sales so I can do an accurate MOM for two years of data.

The issue is when I try to do anything it either blocks me because datetime is a timestamp, but when I cast it then I can't call on the alias.
`

here is my code below where I have the prev_month generated and I also have the date truncated so it sums all totals by the first of that month.

```
 SELECT
  x1,
  x2,
  SUM(amount) AS total,
  LAG(SUM(total)) OVER (PARTITION BY x1, x2 ORDER BY total ASC ) as prev_total,
  prev_total
FROM(
SELECT  
    t2.x1,
    t3.name,
    SUM(amount) AS total,
    DATE_TRUNC(t1.datetime, MONTH) AS total
  FROM testtable1 AS t1
  JOIN testtable2 As t2 ON op = oc
  INNER testtable3 AS t3 ON t3.bc = CAST(t2.ob AS int64)
  INNER JOIN testtable4 AS t4 ON t4.pi = t3.pc
 WHERE t4.pc NOT IN ('MN', 'MN2','MN3', 'OH', 'OI', 'PT', 'RT')
    AND t2.pa = 'FD'
    AND t1.datetime >='2021-01-01'
    AND t2.od <> 'PC'
  GROUP BY 
    op.o_name, 
    bh.b_name,
    pr.P_ActionDateTime
)
GROUP BY
  x1,
  x2,
  prev_total
ORDER BY 
  total DESC;
```

`
is there a way I can insert missing dates even though my datetime field is a timestamp?

in the example below I would want to insert the first of the month of February and record a zero dollar sale. In the data currently if there isn't any amount it doesn't record a timestamp. So when comparing the previous month it will only go to the last month that has sales.

```
example:
datetime   total    prev_total
1/1/2022   $13,000  $11,000   
3/1/2022   $9,0000  $13,000
4/1/2022   $5,000   $9,000

goal:
dateime    total    prev_total
1/1/2022   $13,000  $11,000
2/1/2022   $0       $13,000
3/1/2022   $9,000   $0 
4/1/2022   $5,000   $9,000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a CTE with all months you want to cover taking advantage of the GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY function

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#generate_date_array

Then you can left join the CTE with your query so that months without actual value on your query can be displayed with NULL values.